# Fade in/out FloatingActionButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to slowly fade-in and out a floating action button? I have in my list a FAB to offer the user a way to quickly scroll to the top of the list.

So far I've found in various posts how to detect when the list is scrolled to the top or away from the top (https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac), but I fail to find how I can change the alpha value of a widget. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: `AnimatedOpacity` widget is what you need. Comment if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is from flutter dev page:
With a AnimatedOpacity you can fade any widget. 
Just put you floating action button as child of AnimatedOpacity.
Here is some example:

```
AnimatedOpacity(
  // If the widget is visible, animate to 0.0 (invisible).
  // If the widget is hidden, animate to 1.0 (fully visible).
  opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  // The green box must be a child of the AnimatedOpacity widget.
  child: Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
);
```

[image: fade widget]

You can find more info and full code here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation